# Running C function in matlab without sharing its source code

Tags: c, matlab

How do I convert a simple C function (such as y=a*x**2) into a version that can be run in Matlab, without sharing the original source code? Please help! Thank you.

Comment: Is there something particularly innovative in the assignment `y=a*x**2` that you need to _protect?_ :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo its a task given to me. I kept the function very simple as I want to focus more on the conversion. Or may be it is answer to all life's questions.

Comment: Why would you need C source to call a C function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `mex` file. Matlab will compile a `function.cpp` code to `function.mexw32` or `function.mexw64` (depending of your system architecture), which can be called from Matlab like a normal function. You don't need to share the source, only the compiled file.

It's something like this:

First, you create a `.cpp` file, such as `helloworld.cpp`:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <matrix.h>
#include <mex.h>
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    mexPrintf("Hello World!\n");
}
```

Then, you compile it like this:

```
>> mex helloworld.cpp
```

And call:

```
>> helloworld

Hello World!
```

Take a look at these links for more information on how to create these files:

- [A Short MEX Tutorial and Demo](http://www.shawnlankton.com/2008/03/getting-started-with-mex-a-short-tutorial/)
- [Create C Source MEX-File](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/standalone-example.html)
- [Introducing MEX-Files](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/introducing-mex-files.html)
- [What You Need to Build MEX-Files](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/what-you-need-to-build-mex-files.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could always compile the c function to a .exe, and run that using:

```
system('yourExecutable.exe');
```

You could also try calllib, which seems to be a better answer to your question. Details on this method can be found here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/calllib.html

Let me know if you need more detail, or if this method won't solve the problem.